# Coverage is showing different for full pytest and single app in django using pytest

Tags: django, pytest, testcase, coverage.py

I have created a project in Django, and I'm writing test cases in `pytest`. Now, to use coverage I generally use cmd `coverage run -m pytest`. And to check coverage for a specific app, I report/create *html* files with `coverage html`, so this will create *html* files with red and green markers. Recently, I experimented with different combinations of configurations of coverage and `pytest` and found that when running a full `pytest` with `coverage` like `coverage run -m pytest`  it will not cover all lines, and mark some lines as missing which are actually running while pytest. But when I use pytest with some argument with coverage like `coverage run -m pytest accounts`, it is covering all perfectly and not showing the missing files as I expected.

I have tried running the whole project with `coverage run -m pytest`  and then running `coverage html`  to see in the browser. I got all files' coverage, and to see coverage of specific apps for example `restaurant`, I searched in the top right search box and it's shown below.

**Full Pytest Coverage**

[image]

**Full pytest coverage with searched result**

[image]

Now, I have to run coverage for a specific app so I can do it like:

```
coverage run -m pytest restaurant
```

So this will only run for the restaurant app, then I ran `coverage html`  to see in the browser. Below is an image of the results.

**Restaurant app's Pytest**

[image]

**Restaurant app's Pytest with search result**

[image]

Both are different even though I simultaneously ran them.

I have already used:

- `coverage erase`  before every execution.